# Shopify API - Select all the customer based on tags?

Tags: api, shopify

We have defined all the customers in our shopify store with different tags like "Price Level 1",  "Price Level 2", "Price Level 3" ---- so on till "Price Level 16" and new customer are without any tag. Through the shopify API I want to fetch customers based on there tag, I tried different URL

```
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/customers.json?tags:Price Level 1 
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/customers.json?tags="Price Level 1" 
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/customers.json?query=Price Level 1
```

but all the URL give me the same Result i.e customer with any tag. Please guide me with the best way through which I can fetch the customer based on exact tag name and also how can I fetch the customer without any tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a query you need to use the search endpoint:

```
 https://store.myshopify.com/admin/customers/search.json?query=%27Price%20level%201%27
```

Note when your tags have spaces you have to include quotes in the query. If you are using Node then the easiest way to get this is

```
escape("'Price Level 1'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Its work perfect , I'm getting all the customer who have "Price Level 1" . How can I search if the tags element is empty. i.e "tags": "",

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply one more question . Can I add Tag Using API ?

Comment: Yes of course but you should make it a new question